# Redis - Multi Datacenter Replication - Latency impact

Tags: redis

I'm looking for information on the implications latency has on Redis Replication and Sentinel with a cross data center setup for Geo-HA.

Let's assume the following in regards to server/DC latency:

```
A <> B: 5 ms
A <> C: 25 ms
B <> C: 25 ms
```

The database is used with real-time messaging brokers and therefore we cannot have any long latencies with reads and writes.

1. What impact do network latencies (5 ms, 25 ms) have on read and write operations within a replication setup?
2. How does Sentinel handle such latencies?
3. What would the effect be if C is only a Sentinel instance to the above?